# is this some cross domain issue?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, cross-domain

I am not an expert on fiddler but trying to figure out what is wrong with my configuration.
I have a website on domain example.com which i am hosting on an iframe on another site which is on domain example.org.

example.com has login controls and on successful authentication i have to open a new tab. Chrome and Firefox are working fine, but IE behaves as if i clicked refresh button on Login click.

Traced with Fiddler, but i am not sure what should i be looking looking out for, please help.

Request Header:

```
POST https://example.com/Login/VerifyUserDetails HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 Content-Type: application/json X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest Referer: https://example.com/ Accept-Language: en-US Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko Host: example.com Content-Length: 37 DNT: 1 Connection: Keep-Alive Cache-Control: no-cache

{"userEmail":"abc@gmail.com"}
```

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: public, no-store, max-age=0 Content-Length: 65 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 00:07:28 GMT Last-Modified: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 00:07:28 GMT Vary: * Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://example.org*.example.com *.example.org; X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 00:07:38 GMT

{"IsADUser":false,"IsActiveUser":false,"PasswordSetError":""}
```

Please guide.

Although i think someone with expertise on this might find this interesting that the immediate next call after authentication is a redirect to which i see below response:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Should start by showing the code that is causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I need to add the domain that I am hosting in the iframe in IE trusted sites. It works. :) So, it was not a cross domain scripting issue, I am using the w3c recommended content security policy.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to it, I had to add p3p policy to the site. I had the domain in my IE trusted site list so it worked for me with above solution. But, one external user didn't have our domain in whitelist and he kept getting 401 errors. 
I searched a lot and have to add a valid p3p token for it to work. Not any p3p policy, but a valid one unlike other suggestions that I found on the net.